# Return Enum type in grpc C#

Tags: c#, grpc

I write a grpc service that returns an enum type message on one of the services

GRPC Protobf :

```
syntax = "proto3";
package TeamWaveNetworkPackage;


message Member{
string MemberId = 1;
string MemberEmail = 2; 
string MemberPassphar = 3;
string MemberFullName = 4;
string MemberPhoto = 5;
}
message NoneTransportResponce{

    enum Responce{
    UserCreated = 0;
    }
}

service AuthurationService{

rpc SignInUser(Member) returns(NoneTransportResponce);
    
}
```

when I want to return response :

```
public override async Task<NoneTransportResponce> SignUpUser(Member member, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            
            if (MemberAsistant.AddMember(member))
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(NoneTransportResponce.Types.Responce.UserCreated);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

error :
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'TeamWaveNetworkPackage.NoneTransportResponce.Types.Responce' to 'TeamWaveNetworkPackage.NoneTransportResponce'**

how return enum type in Response ????

Comment: you can specify `FromResult<T>` and make sure you are passing the expected return type to FromResult method

Comment: Read the error. It says you tried to return a `TeamWaveNetworkPackage.NoneTransportResponce.Types.Responce` when your method's return type is `TeamWaveNetworkPackage.NoneTransportResponce`. Either return a `NoneTransportResponce` with `return NoneTransportResponce` or change the return type to `NoneTransportResponce.Types.Responce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, note that your `NoneTransportResponce` type is empty; it doesn't actually *have* a per-instance `Responce` field; for that, you'd need something like:

```
message NoneTransportResponce{
    Responce responceType = 1;
    enum Responce{
        UserCreated = 0;
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to use (because you need to return a `NoneTransportResponce` message, not a `NoneTransportResponce.Responce` enum value):

```cs
if (MemberAsistant.AddMember(member))
{
    return new NoneTransportResponce
    {
        ResponceType = Responce.UserCreated
    };
}
```

or something very similar. Note you don't need the `Task.FromResult` etc, unless you have no async code at all, in which case, remove the `async` and use `return Task.FromResult(new NoneTransportResponce {...});`.